# Query store plan is not forcing and there is no failure reason

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, query-store

I have forced a plan in query store as follows

`EXEC sys.sp_query_store_force_plan @query_id = 113366, @plan_id = 3687662`

but when I run the query again, the query does not use the plan, nor does it show a `failure_force_reason`

The following query shows that the plan has been forced and suggests no failure in forcing on the last run

```
SELECT  plan_id,
        query_id,
        is_forced_plan,
        last_force_failure_reason_desc
FROM    sys.query_store_plan
WHERE   is_forced_plan = 1
```

[image]

The following query shows the last runtime of the query in question, this confirms to me that it was indeed this query that I re-ran and that it used a different plan to the one I forced:

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        q.query_id,
        p.plan_id,
        s.last_execution_time,
        SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS CurrentTime
FROM    sys.query_store_query q
        JOIN sys.query_store_plan p
            ON q.query_id = p.query_id
        JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats s
            ON s.plan_id = p.plan_id
WHERE   q.query_id = 113366
ORDER BY s.last_execution_time DESC
```

[image]

Why does query store seem to ignore this plan force? Are there any extended events or other troubleshooting tools I can leverage to understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the plan it uses similar to what you're trying to force?

Forcing the plan doesn't guarantee that the exact plan will be forced. It can still use a morally equivalent plan.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) (emphasis mine):

> The resulting execution plan forced by this feature will be the same **or similar** to the plan being forced. Because the resulting plan may not be identical to the plan specified by sys.sp_query_store_force_plan, the performance of the plans may vary. In rare cases, the performance difference may be significant and negative; in that case, the administrator must remove the forced plan.

Kendra Little [writes about this](https://littlekendra.com/2018/03/12/what-is-a-morally-equivalent-execution-plan-and-why-is-it-good/) in detail.

Comment: spot on! I'd forced a plan of the same (or very similar) shape. Once I found a previous one of a different shape, the force worked. Kendra's article is brilliant and makes this much clearer than the official docs IMO